# iOS Card *card=[self.deck drawRandomCard]; Causing Thread 1:signal SIGABRT

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios7, ios8

I am doing Stanford iOS7 CS193P Lecture2 homework ,there is a problem i don't understand .Interesting thing is this happen when i fliped card sencond time. 
Here is wraning    libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "PlayingCardDeck.h"
@interface ViewController ()
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *fliplabel;
@property(strong,nonatomic)Deck *deck;
@property(nonatomic)int flipscount;
@end

@implementation ViewController
-(void)setFlipscount:(int)flipscount
{
    _flipscount=flipscount;
    self.fliplabel.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Flips: %d",self.flipscount];
}

-(Deck *)deck
{
    if (!_deck)
        _deck=[self createDeck];
        return _deck;

}

-(Deck *)createDeck;
{
    return [[PlayingCardDeck alloc] init];
}

- (IBAction)touchCardButton:(UIButton *)sender {
        if ([sender.currentTitle length]) {
            [sender setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"cardback"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [sender setTitle:@"" forState:(UIControlStateNormal)];
        }else{
            Card *card=[self.deck drawRandomCard];
            [sender setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"cardfront"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [sender setTitle:[card contents] forState:(UIControlStateNormal)];
        }


    self.flipscount++;
}
```

If i delete Card *card=[self.deck drawRandomCard] in (IBAction)touchCardButton:(UIButton *)sender then it work fine,how is that happen,how can i fix it,somebody please help me
PS:I didn't change my label name

There is my error page:

```
 int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
        @autoreleasepool {
            return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
        }
    }
**Thread1:signal SIGABRT**
```

There is my output:

```
    25  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000010a412145 start + 1
    26  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

There is my drawRandomCards:

```
-(Card *)drawRandomCard
{
    Card *randomcardCard=nil;
    unsigned index = arc4random() % [self.cards count];
    randomcardCard = self.cards[index];
    [self.cards removeObjectAtIndex:index];
    return randomcardCard;
}
```

Comment: Show the whole error message. And could you also show what's in `drawRandomCard`?

Comment: @Larme I put my error message and drawRandomCard above.

Comment: If you go to Xcode's breakpoint navigator and add a breakpoint on all Objective-C exceptions, the error should cause you to stop at a useful place instead of inside `main()`.  That would lead you to the actual line that's causing trouble.

Comment: By the way, what is the value of `[self.cards count]` in `drawRandomCard` when you hit the error?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, check the "index" value in "drawRandomCard". Maybe the self.cards array don't have the index you're getting in

```
randomcardCard = self.cards[index];
```